# Automatic region of interests for 2D images

Tags: image-processing, image

I have a picture displaying certain remarkable features (high intensity peaks).
Is there a function that allows me to automatically draw a (Region Of Interests) ROI around the features and crop the initial image according to this ROI ?

The initial image

[image: This is the test image]

the ROI

[image: This is the ROI to be automatically detected more or less]

The final image after cropping

[image: This is the final picture]

Any idea ? Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xt1Q.jpg"];
lsImgKeyPoints = ImageKeypoints[img];
BoundingRegion[lsImgKeyPoints]

HighlightImage[img, BoundingRegion[lsImgKeyPoints]]

ImageTrim[img, BoundingRegion[lsImgKeyPoints]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: @yfs Welcome, good luck!